# Java converting to Jython-Getting a class object within itself

Tags: java, python, jython

I am attempting to convert Java code to Jython and am using the apache Log and LogFactory imports.  I am attempting to emulate Foo.class in Jython The chunk of code is as follows: 
in Java

```
    import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
    import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

    public class MyClass {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MyClass.class);

    public MyClass(Document dom)
    { //code
    }
```

How can I emulate this same behavior of MyClass.class in Jython/Python?

Comment: You do realize you can import java classes _in_ jython right?

Comment: Yes I have the imports, The issue is emulating MyClass.class

Answer (score 3):

To illustrate my comment:

```
from org.apache.commons.logging import LogFactory

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, dom):
        "code"

log = LogFactory.getLog(MyClass)
```

Or

```
MyClass.log = LogFactory.getLog(MyClass)
```

Comment: I suspect OP didn't grasp that in jython `MyClass` corresponds to java's `MyClass.class`, i.e. there is no `.class` attribute of a class